# How to send asynchronous Http Response?

Tags: java, design-patterns, httpresponse

I have created a Rest API that takes a request and gives response to the client. But My API is dependent on a third party service, that instead of giving a response, give a callback to my other endpoint. In order to send the service I need to wait for the callback to be received. How can I achieve it?

My Rest API that needs to send the response.

```
@POST
//  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
//  @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public ConnectResponse connectAPI(String connectString, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headers.getRequestHeaders().entrySet()) {
            logger.info("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
            for (String eachEntry : entry.getValue()) {
                logger.info("eachEntry " + eachEntry);
            }
        }
        logger.info("USSD received " + connectString);
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- in connect post request ----------------------");
        ConnectRequest requestObj = new ConnectRequest();
        try {
            if (connectString != null && connectString.startsWith("<")) {
                requestObj = marshallConnectRequest(connectString);
            } else {
                requestObj = convertKeyValueToObject(connectString);
            }

            logger.info("Request is " + requestObj);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error("----------------- Error in UnMarshalling ----------");
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        ConnectResponse connectResponse = new ConnectResponse();
        connectResponse.setSession(requestObj.getSessionid());
        connectResponse.setText("Hello");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        logger.info("---------- returning response ----------------------");
        return connectResponse;
    }

    public ConnectRequest marshallConnectRequest(String connectString) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ConnectRequest.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        return (ConnectRequest) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(connectString));
    }

    public ConnectRequest convertKeyValueToObject(String connectString) {
        return new ConnectRequest();
    }
```

Instead of sending a simple response object I want to wait for the callback to hit at the following API.

```
@Path("/rest")
public class RESTWebservice {
    /*
     * @Context private MessageContext messageContext;
     */
    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RESTWebservice.class);

    @POST
    @Path("/sendResponse")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseJSON postQuestionnaire(RequestJSON requestJson) {
    // performing operations
}
```

Call flow : -

1. Client will call connectAPI which will call a third party API.
2. The third party API after processing above call will callback postQuestionnaire.
3. The connectAPI will send response only when the callback at postQuestionnaire is received.

Comment: The client will call ````postQuestionnaire```` api and this api will call the third party service and the third party service will call your ````rest/sendResponse```` api?

Comment: I have edited the question and added a Call flow section

Comment: As I understand the third party library is not returning a response, and instead it is redirecting to the postQuestionnaire api, so have you tried to catch the response of postQuestionnaire  api inside the connectAPI?

Comment: No I have not tried that approach, I want to catch the request of postquestionnaire inside the connectAPI. Can you guide me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally this should be your flow

1. Client will call connectAPI which will call a third party API.
2. The third party API after processing above call will callback
   postQuestionnaire. ---> This should be done seperate thread using `Callable` Task using executor service. Then you will have `Future<ResponseFromPOstQuestionnaire>` returned from executor service `submit` call
3. The connectAPI will send response only when the
   callback at postQuestionnaire is received. ---> Once you hacve `Future` object you can do wait on by calling `.get()` (this is blocking call) so it will wait for response to come then you can return the same response or modified respone back to client.

Example on how to use callable task with executor service is explain here -> https://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example

Comment: @Mudit Agrawal, did you get the solution with this answer? Can you please share your answer? I have the exact same requirement.